# D3v4 - update / cycle through data

Tags: d3.js

I have a set of datapoints, each point has multiple y values

```
x: number;
y: Array<{key:string, value:number}>;
```

I use the following function to get the correct data points for a key:

```
function dataForKey(data, key)
{
  return data.map(function(d)
  {
    return {
      x: d.x,
      y: findCorrespondingDataPoint(d.y, key)
    };
  });
}
```

I am struggling however to make D3 walk through all the available datapoints (by `key`) and transition from 1 to the next in a given sequence.
I have seen a few examples using `transition().tween(..)` and data interpolation, but I don't think that's what I want, since I just want to transition from one value to the next.
Something along these lines:

```
// pseudo code
for(key in keys)
{
    d3.selectAll(".dot")
       .transition(t)
       .data(dataForKey(key))
       .waitForTransitionToFinish()
}
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this using D3v4?